# How to get a layout of Divs that looks like this? Better way than trying to use Ionic Grid?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get a css layout like the one below. It would consist of 6 divs total... 3 on top and 3 on the bottom. I'm wanting them to be static sizes so they don't change height/width. I'm using angular/ionic and tried to use an ionic grid but couldn't get the spacing to look correct using a grid system.
I'm filling each box with a directive/component but can handle the css around that part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with flexbox

```css
.d-flex {
    display: flex ;
    height: 200px;
    &.short {
        height: 40px;
    }
    div {
        flex: 1 1 0 ;
        border: solid 1px black ;
        &.small {
            flex-grow: 0;
            min-width: 50px;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class=""></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex short">
        <div class=""></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class=""></div>
    </div>
```